# Three way merge sort problem not sorting correctly

Tags: java, mergesort

I've been working on this three way merge sort algorithm which I based off of my normal merge sort code; however, it isn't sorting correctly and so I believe there might be a minor mistake in my code. Any help please? I've been looking into the code for 3 hours trying to find the problem but it has proven difficult.

```
public class TriMergeSort {

    void merge(int arr[], int low, int mid1, int mid2, int high) { 
        int sizeA = mid1 - low + 1; 
        int sizeB =  mid2 - mid1;
        int sizeC = high - mid2;

        int A[] = new int[sizeA]; 
        int B[] = new int[sizeB]; 
        int C[] = new int[sizeC];

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++) 
            A[i] = arr[low + i]; 
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeB; j++) 
            B[j] = arr[mid1 + j + 1]; 
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeC; x++) 
            C[x] = arr[mid2 + x + 1];

        int i = 0, j = 0, x = 0; 
        int k = low; 
        
        while (i < sizeA && j < sizeB && x < sizeC) {
            
            if (A[i] < B[j] && A[i] < C[x]) { 
                arr[k] = A[i]; 
                i++; 
            } else
            if (A[i] >= B[j] && B[j] < C[x]) { 
                arr[k] = B[j]; 
                j++; 
            } else
            if (A[i] > C[x] && B[j] >= C[x]) { 
                arr[k] = C[x]; 
                x++; 
            } 
            k++; 
        } 

        while (i < sizeA) { 
            arr[k] = A[i]; 
            i++; 
            k++; 
        } 

        while (j < sizeB) { 
            arr[k] = B[j]; 
            j++; 
            k++; 
        } 
        
        while (x < sizeC) { 
            arr[k] = C[x]; 
            x++; 
            k++; 
        }
    } 

    void sort(int arr[], int low, int high) { 
        
        if (low < high) {  
            int mid1 = low + ((high - low) / 3); 
            int mid2 = low + 2 * ((high - low) / 3) + 1;

            sort(arr, low, mid1); 
            sort(arr, mid1 + 1, mid2); 
            sort(arr, mid2 + 1, high);

            merge(arr, low, mid1, mid2, high); 
        } 
    } 

    static void print(int arr[]) { 
        int n = arr.length; 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " "); 
        System.out.println(); 
    } 

    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        int arr[] = { 15, 2, 6, 7, 55, 0, 28, 41, 12 }; 

        TriMergeSort test = new TriMergeSort(); 
        test.sort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1); 

        print(arr); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a debugger is an important skill, it's a good opportunity to learn it

Comment: You did not post the code for the 3-way merge sort that does not work.

Comment: Edited the post to display my 3 way merge sort... my bad

Comment: Unrelated, please follow java naming conventions. Your array names should start lowercase too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code posted in the question works fine. You did not post the 3-way merge code you have problems with.

Note that instead of passing `high` as the index to the last item in the slice to sort, you should pass the index of the first element beyond the slice. This allows for simpler code, without confusing and error prone `+1`/`-1` adjustments.

Here is a modified version:

```java
public class MergeSort { 

    void merge(int arr[], int low, int mid, int high) { 
        int sizeA = mid - low; 
        int sizeB = high - mid; 

        int A[] = new int[sizeA]; 
        int B[] = new int[sizeB]; 

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++) 
            A[i] = arr[low + i]; 
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeB; j++) 
            B[j] = arr[mid + j]; 

        int i = 0, j = 0; 
        int k = low; 
        
        while (i < sizeA && j < sizeB) { 
            if (A[i] <= B[j]) { 
                arr[k++] = A[i++]; 
            } else { 
                arr[k++] = B[j++]; 
            } 
        } 

        while (i < sizeA) {
            arr[k++] = A[i++];
        } 

        while (j < sizeB) { 
            arr[k++] = B[j++];
        } 
    } 

    void sort(int arr[], int low, int high) { 
        if (high - low >= 2) {  
            int mid = low + (high - low) / 2; 
            sort(arr, low, mid); 
            sort(arr, mid, high); 
            merge(arr, low, mid, high); 
        } 
    } 

    static void print(int arr[]) { 
        int n = arr.length; 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(); 
    } 

    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        int arr[] = { 15, 2, 6, 7, 55, 0, 28, 41, 12, 10, 59 }; 
        MergeSort test = new MergeSort(); 
        test.sort(arr, 0, arr.length); 
        print(arr); 
    } 
}
```

To convert this into a 3-way merge version, `sort3` must follow these steps:

- split the range into 3 slices instead of 2. The first slice runs from `low` to `mid1 = low + (high - low)/3` excluded, the second from `mid1` to `mid2 = low + (high - low)*2/3` excluded and the third from `mid2` to `high` excluded.
- sort each of the 3 subslices recursively
- call `merge3(arr, low, mid1, mid2, high)`

  - make copies of the 3 subslices
  - write a loop for 3 index values running the 3 slices until one of them is exhausted
  - write 3 loops for the 2 remaining slices (A and B) or (B and C) or (A and C),
  - write 3 loops to copy the remaining elements from the remaining slice, A, B or C

**EDIT:** the `merge` function in your `TriMergeSort` class is missing the 3 loops that merge 2 slices once one of the 3 initial slices is exhausted. This explains why the array does not get properly sorted. After the 3-way merge loop, you should have:

```
    while (i < sizeA && j < sizeB) {
        ...
    }
    while (i < sizeA && x < sizeC) {
        ...
    }
    while (j < sizeB && x < sizeC) {
        ...
    }
```

To avoid all these repeated loops, you could combine tests on the index values into a single loop body:

```c
public class TriMergeSort {

    void merge(int arr[], int low, int mid1, int mid2, int high) { 
        int sizeA = mid1 - low; 
        int sizeB = mid2 - mid1;
        int sizeC = high - mid2;

        int A[] = new int[sizeA]; 
        int B[] = new int[sizeB]; 
        int C[] = new int[sizeC];

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++) 
            A[i] = arr[low + i]; 
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeB; j++) 
            B[j] = arr[mid1 + j]; 
        for (int k = 0; k < sizeC; k++) 
            C[k] = arr[mid2 + k];

        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        
        while (low < high) {
            if (i < sizeA && (j >= sizeB || A[i] <= B[j])) {
                if (k >= sizeC || A[i] <= C[k]) {
                    arr[low++] = A[i++];
                } else {
                    arr[low++] = C[k++];
                }
            } else {
                if (j < sizeB && (k >= sizeC || B[j] <= C[k])) {
                    arr[low++] = B[j++];
                } else {
                    arr[low++] = C[k++];
                }
            }
        } 
    } 

    void sort(int arr[], int low, int high) { 
        if (high - low >= 2) {  
            int mid1 = low + (high - low) / 3; 
            int mid2 = low + (high - low) * 2 / 3;
            sort(arr, low, mid1); 
            sort(arr, mid1, mid2); 
            sort(arr, mid2, high);
            merge(arr, low, mid1, mid2, high); 
        } 
    } 

    static void print(int arr[]) { 
        int n = arr.length; 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(); 
    } 

    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        int arr[] = { 15, 2, 6, 7, 55, 0, 28, 41, 12 }; 
        TriMergeSort test = new TriMergeSort(); 
        test.sort(arr, 0, arr.length); 
        print(arr); 
    }
}
```

The `while` loop above can be further simplified but somewhat less readable as:

```
    while (low < high) {
        if (i < sizeA && (j >= sizeB || A[i] <= B[j])) {
            arr[low++] = (k >= sizeC || A[i] <= C[k]) ? A[i++] : C[k++];
        } else {
            arr[low++] = (j < sizeB && (k >= sizeC || B[j] <= C[k])) ? B[j++] : C[k++];
        }
    }
```

And even one step further:

```
    while (low < high) {
        arr[low++] = (i < sizeA && (j >= sizeB || A[i] <= B[j])) ?
            ((k >= sizeC || A[i] <= C[k]) ? A[i++] : C[k++]) :
            (j < sizeB && (k >= sizeC || B[j] <= C[k])) ? B[j++] : C[k++];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the tips! I edited the post to display my 3- way merge sort algorithm as I had accidentally posted the regular merge sort.